# Google Map Deployement Or Publishing Problem in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

i created google map test application on two difference computers A, B 
i created two MD5 finger prints on both and obtained two different keys from google for Computer A and B.

Key of Computer A does not show google map on Computer B and vise versa.
Key of computer A only shows google map on Computer a only and same case with key B.

now if i deploy or publish that project to use in android mobile which key will i be using ???

i am confused.. please guide..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final fingerprint will depend on what keystore you're using to create it with. The emulator runs Google Maps with the `debug.keystore` which is not identical for the two computers - hence the different fingerprints.

You cannot publish an application to the market that is signed with `debug.keystore`. You need to create your own keystore, sign your application with that, and it is for *that* keystore that the final fingerprint needs to be created.

Given that; it should work just fine.

**Edit in response to your comment**

Yes, in order to make the andriod market accept your application, you need to sign it yourself with a keystore that you create. You can read more about this at Android Developers under [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html), but in short, you use *keytool* which should be in your java install path (or just do a quick search through your computer for `keytool.exe`).

While developing, you can still push your application signed with `debug.keystore` to any mobile phone for testing. An easy way to install it is to upload the apk file to somewhere on the web, and pointing your mobile browser to that address. But for *Market* you need to use your own keystore, and you'll need to create a new fingerprint for that keystore. Also note that if you have installed the debug-signed apk file on your phone, you'll need to manually uninstall the app before you install the same app signed with a different keystore. If you just try to download the new version from market and install it, you'll get a generic "could not install" error message.

Comment: do you have any example of creating mine own keystore???
if i dont create my own key store i wont work on mobile phone?? in short what i understood??